# Get data value to show on alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code. I need to retrieve the value of what is there in the .data. It shows up blank although I know it does have a value when I show it on the form.

```js
$('#Settings').on('click', '#senpop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.field-validation-error').find('span').text('');
  $('#SensName').text($(this).data('sensname'));
  $('#SelectSenID').val($(this).data('sens'));

  // Note that the above code updates the values fine for the elements above. Below I am trying to get the value of "sensname" to show up in an alert but shows blank. 
  // I know there is a value because it does show up properly on the form but not able to 
  // retrieve it here. 

  var sens = $("#senpop");
  var inf = sens.data("sensname");
  alert(inf);

  $('#ViewModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: true,
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md header_mobile">Name</div>
<div class="mobile_data">
  <a href="#" id="senpop" data-sens="@item.Sens" data-sensname="@item.SensName">@item.Name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `alert()` for debugging as it silently coerces datatypes, use `console.log()` instead. Secondly, you're missing a `)` at the end of the JS - is that just a typo? Check the console for errors. Also ensure that `#senpop` is a child of `#Settings`, otherwise the event will never be caught.

Comment: Are you seeing the alert?

Comment: @Balmar Yes the alert does come on but it is blank. I know it fires fine and I do see the value on the form. I need to grab the value for something I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the `data-sensname` has a value in your HTML? Ie. is `@item.SensName` actually giving a value?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes, correct. SensName is giving a value. I just cannot retrieve it as I need to grab this value and use it for something. As mentioned, it does show up on the element.

Comment: Just to be sure, how many elements with `id="senpop"` do you have in your document? Maybe the second data-call is on a different element than your first one. JsFiddle is just alerting the proper value: http://jsfiddle.net/2qzrdL4f/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was missing this (this) keyword to reference the specific row that I was on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the data attribute printing in Chrome and Firefox with the following set up.

First - yes, best practice not to use `alert()` for debugging like this. Always default to `console.log()`.

Next, I'm guessing your HTML structure is more like this:

```
<div id="Settings">
  Settings
  <div class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md header_mobile">Name</div>
  <div class="mobile_data">
    <a href="#" id="senpop" data-sens="@item.Sens" data-sensname="@item.SensName">@item.Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

... because you're binding the `click` handler to a `#Settings` element. Make sure that the `#Settings` element is not an `<a>`, because it's not valid to nest `<a>` tags.

Next, make sure to either put jQuery and your js script just above the closing `</body>` tag, which is a best practice

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/yourscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

...or, wrap your script in a a `document.ready` if you can't add script to the body for whatever reason:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // your js code
});
```

**So, this is the working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Settings">
      Settings
      <div class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md header_mobile">Name</div>
      <div class="mobile_data">
        <a href="#" id="senpop" data-sens="@item.Sens" data-sensname="@item.SensName">@item.Name</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#Settings').on('click', '#senpop', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('#settings clicked');
      $('.field-validation-error').find('span').text('');
      $('#SensName').text($(this).data('sensname'));
      $('#SelectSenID').val($(this).data('sens'));

      // Below I am trying to get the value of sensor to show up in an alert but shows blank.
      // I know there is a value because it does show up properly on the form but not able to
      // retrieve it here.

      var sens = $("#senpop");
      var inf = sens.data("sensname");
      console.log(inf);

      $('#ViewModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true,
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of running this code and clicking `#senpop`:

[image: screenshot of working page in chrome and firefox]